# How to set same url for different elements

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to set same URL for different elements on a click event:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var realStateBtn = $('#real-estate-center').parent();
    var link = $('#real-estate-center > .linkwidth');
    var realStateClass = $('.real-estate-center');
    var bankOwnedProps = $('#bank-owned-properties > span');
    var findYourHomesValue = $('#find-your-homes-value > span');

    realStateBtn.css('zIndex', 9999);

    realStateBtn.click(function() {
        window.location.href='https://realestatecenter.bankofamerica.com/';
    });

    link.click(function() {
        window.location.href="https://realestatecenter.bankofamerica.com/";
    });

    realStateClass.click(function() {
        window.location.href="https://realestatecenter.bankofamerica.com/";
    });     

    findYourHomesValue.click(function() {
        window.location.href="http://realestatecenter.bankofamerica.com/tools/marketvalue.aspx";
    });

    bankOwnedProps.click(function() {
        window.location.href="http://realestatecenter.bankofamerica.com/";
    });
});
```

I am calling this method in some different functions:

`window.location.href="http://realestatecenter.bankofamerica.com/";`

That's what I want to avoid, I want to use only once.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Put a common class on the elements you want to change?

Answer (score 1):

You could set a home page variable and just use that like so

```
var homePageUrl = "http://realestatecenter.bankofamerica.com/"
```

and just pass `window.location.href = homePageUrl`

you could also make it its own function like

```
function redirect(path) {
 window.location.href = path
}
```

and then call that function in each place with the url as the argument that way at least you are sourcing everything to one function vs duplicating code